# How many ports a process can use or bind at a time?

Tags: java, operating-system, port

How many OS ports can a single process can hold simultaneously ? Is there any limit ?
I am asking this from the java `ServerSocket` context. In my case it is a simulation application in which I created more than one -4  java server sockets listnening to 4 different ports in order to simulate 4 devices which would do the same. That's why I am wondering is there any restriction by OS (I am using Windows 7 ,32 bit)?

Comment: What OS?? That information is a little crucial to the question.

Comment: When you are listening, some else need to know where you are listening. Typically you expose one (or couple of them) port for service.  Are you sure you want to listen on many (how many)ports?

Comment: @BoristheSpider see my edit- it's Windows

Comment: @Jayan It is a simulation application. In this, I need to start 4 serversockets listening 4 dfferent ports in order to simulate 4 devices which would do it in real case.Then I think about this question

Comment: Four listening sockets isn't a problem. Four thousand might be. You should treat them as a scarce resource and consume them as conservatively as possible.

Comment: Could you explain a bit simulation itself ? Are you simulating 4 clients connecting to one server or 4 servers ?

Comment: @ user3360241 4-servers ,clients can be any number

Answer (score 1):

Between **1024 - 49152**, but the upper limit might be different depending on OS.

Ports 0 - 1023 are reserved by the Internet Engineering Task Force for Assigned Names and Numbers. These are so called well known ports and are to be used by the application end points that communicate using TCP/UDP.

Dynamic ports from range 49152 through 65535 are reserved for outbound requests.

However, it looks strange that you would expose Server on so many ports. It would be highly inconvenient for clients of such Server to keep track of 48129 available ports.

Comment: Define "most applications"? Lots of well known services use several ports SMB and FTP for example.

Comment: @user3360241 - In my program I am creating 4 different Serversocket with 4 different ports - Not a single Serversocket

Comment: You have got a point there. I overly emphasized that having 48129 listening ports is probably not a good thing.

Comment: Of course you can have multiple Server Sockets, however these Server Sockets should be listeners for different services/protocols. Are you trying to achieve scalability by having Server Socket per client ?

Comment: Yes, having a server socket per client would indeed be very silly.